# Flutter module can't connect internet

Tags: flutter, flutter-module

Recently i working integrate flutter module to android native app, but i got problem.

- With debug app, flutter module working normal with internet.
- But after release app , flutter module cant connect the internet. The feature of android native still working with internet, but feature of flutter module not work, i cant load image, or some thing.
- So i research, almost solution is add INTERNET permission to android manifest, but it not working.
  Is anyone facing this issue?

Make flutter module connect internet with release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have found problem.
Release mode use

```
minifyEnabled true
```

It is reason flutter module can't connect the internet.
Solution
update proguard file

```
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.embedding.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**
```